# How to retrieve node and particular element string from xml file in C++ using libxml2 by using xpath?

Tags: c++, xml, xpath, domparser

How to retrieve text value in c++ using libxml?

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Help xmlns="http://www.example.org/HelpFileStructure" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/HelpFileStructure HelpFileStructure.xsd ">
  <Text>dfgdfg</Text>
</Help>
```

Code:

```
void Help::HelpName()
{
    string Help_text;
    parser.parse_file(XmlFileName);
    Node* root = parser.get_document()->get_root_node();
    NodeSet result = root->find("/Help/Text");
    Element *first_element = (Element *)result.at(0);
    Help_text = first_element->get_child_text()->get_content();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```c
NodeSet result = root->find("//*[local-name()='Help']/*[local-name()='Text']");
```

That gets a node set where each node is an element named `Text`, regardless of what namespace the element is in, that’s a child of any element named `Help`, regardless of what namespace it’s in.

If you only want `Help` and `Text` elements in the `http://www.example.org/HelpFileStructure` namespace, and want to ignore any `Text` and `Help` elements the document might have that are in some other namespace, then you can use the `namespace-uri()` function like this:

```c
NodeSet result = root->find("//*[local-name()='Help' and namespace-uri()='http://www.example.org/HelpFileStructure']/*[local-name()='Text' and namespace-uri()='http://www.example.org/HelpFileStructure']");
```

Comment: When i removed xmlns="http://www.example.org/HelpFileStructure" from xml file. It's working. i got the error "unable to find string literal operator 'operator""Help' with 'const char [39]', 'long long unsigned int' arguments" followed above procedure

Comment: Commented this line app working without crash but, i'm not getting string value Element *first_element = (Element *)result.at(0);

Comment: See the updated answer. I see now that after the `.find()`, the code as written in the question is expecting to get the text content of the first node from the node set.

Comment: About the `"unable to find string literal operator 'operator""Help'` error, I think that was just due to the nested double quotation marks I had in the initial answer. The answer is changed now to use single quotes around element names, so that should solve the problem.